# I would vs I will (again)

Tags: word-usage

I know there have been similar questions in the past but I couldn't quite grasp the correct usage. I have been using version 1 of the phrase below for years at work, and recently a colleague said it should be version 2 instead. Are both correct, or is only version 2 correct? Context is when there is a new task or issue at work, and I want to leave it to another colleague to handle it:

**Version 1:** I'd / I would leave it to you
**Version 2:** I'll / I will leave it to you

Answer (score 1):

I think [this article](https://preply.com/en/blog/how-to-use-will-and-would-in-english) will be a great resource for you.  Your use fits the promise/predictions case.

We typically use *will* instead of *would* when we want to firmly state something.  Since there is no uncertainty about whether or not you will leave this task to your colleague, use *will*.

There are times when the *would* version of the sentence is more natural:

**Jane:** "Who would you leave your work to if you had to go on vacation?"

**Jack:** "I would leave it to you."

Answer (score 1):

If I say

> I would leave it to you (***if that's ok with you***).

I am a tiny bit more polite than if I say

> I will leave it to you (***whether you want to do it or not***).

But truly, in spoken language the difference is negligeable.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much difference, and there would likely be no misunderstanding the meaning regardless of which one you used.

Using 'would' implies that it is the choice you would make if the circustances were such that you are (or were) going to make the choice, or if the choice is going to be made in the future, not right at the time of speaking. Using 'will' also implies future, but almost certainly immediate future. Both are going to be understood to mean "I leave it to you".

Edit: removed the word 'not', as it reversed what I actually meant.

Comment: Thank you. Does it mean that using "would" implies I haven't actually made the decision yet, but it will ultimately still be "you" who I will leave the task to? Is it typically more political/casual to use "would" over "will" in this context?

Comment: That last sentence, it should be "Both *are* going to be understood to mean 'I leave it to you'", right?

Comment: @mjjf You are right, that's what I meant -- I've edited the post to remove that. I must have been going to write 'not be misunderstood' or something.

Comment: @Dan 'would' implies something that hasn't happened yet and will only happen under certain conditions; 'will' means that something hasn't happened yet but no conditions are necessary for it to happen in the future. So 'will' is more definite, but unless the speaker emphasizes the word 'would' and maybe mentions the conditions ("if management tells me I'm the one who decides, I would leave it to you"), then all three of these statements will likely be understood to mean that 'it' is being left to the hearer.

Answer (score 0):

"Will" is the indicative mood. It's used for simply stating facts. "Would" is generally an irrealis mood, which is used for discussing things in counterfactual situations. For instance, you can say "If I weren't available, I would leave it to you". Because of this, it implies the opposite of what you mean; it would normally be used when you aren't going to leave it to them, but are explaining situations where you would. "Would" can also be used to express hope, as in "Would that be the case", but that is more of an archaic use.